# Apache.NMS.AMQP 2.0.0 library when publishing is throwing org.apache.qpid.proton.amqp.UnsignedByte cannot be cast to java.lang.byte error

Tags: c#, .net, amqp, activemq-artemis

I am using Apache.NMS.AMQP library in our .netcore 5 project. We connect to Apache ActiveMQ Artemis as a middle layer for the event driven architecture using AMQP protocol.

There is no issue in consuming messages from the same amqp protocol; but when publishing to a topic, we are getting some errors.

broker URI:

`failover:(amqp://localhost:5672)?transport.startupMaxReconnectAttempts=1&transport.randomize=false`

Code:

```
var _factory = new Apache.NMS.AMQP.ConnectionFactory(_connectURI);

IConnection connection = _factory.CreateConnection(username,password);
ISession session = connection.CreateSession(AcknowledgementMode.AutoAcknowledge);

ITextMessage msg = session.CreateTextMessage(stringMessage);
var topicDestination = SessionUtil.GetTopic(session, topic);
connection.Start();`

IMessageProducer publisher = session.CreateProducer(topicDestination);
publisher.DeliveryMode = MsgDeliveryMode.Persistent;
publisher.Send(msg);
```

Error that I'm getting:

> Message ID: xxxx:2:1:1-1 rejected, Description = org.apache.qpid.proton.amqp.UnsignedByte cannot be cast to java.lang.byte

I tried several combinations of sending the same from different methods, added Apache.NMS library on top of it as well. But still no luck.

Anyone have come across this issue?

Comment: Are you seeing this problem on the client or on the broker?

Comment: @JustinBertram It's on the client. its Apache.NMS.NMSException --> Apache.NMS.AMQP.Util.NMSProviderError: failed.. at Apache.NMS.AMQP.Provider.Amqp.AmqpProducer.SendAsync,,,

Comment: The fact that the tiny bit of error message shows "org.apache.qpid.proton.amqp" would indicate the error was propagated from the broker as that is a proton-j type.  Inspecting broker logs and trying to find details there would help.

Comment: @TimBish I agree the same. This seems to be an issue with the amq-broker-7.2.1 version I'm using. Will check with the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used amq broker 7.10 and the issue is sorted in the broker.